# Simplify with algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I'm having trouble with simplifying the equation below. When I put it into wolfram, it says I should get 1, but I just can't get there. Any help would be great;

$$|\frac{x-y-(x+y)e^{2iyL}}{x+y-(x-y)e^{2iyL}}|^2$$

Comment: That expression does not simplify to $1$. For example, if you put $x=y$ it reduces to $-e^{2iyL}$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I need to edit it. I forgot to put the absolute value squared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $x$, $y$ and $L$ are real numbers.

If $x\neq y$, set $a = (x+y)/(x-y)$ and $b=2yL$. Then we have

$$\left\vert \frac{1-ae^{ib}}{a-e^{ib}} \right\vert^2 = \frac{1-ae^{ib}}{a-e^{ib}} \cdot \overline{\frac{1-ae^{ib}}{a-e^{ib}}},$$

since $|z|^2 = z \bar{z}$. Now $a$ is a real number so it is its own complex conjugate, and the conjugate of $e^{ib}$ is $e^{-ib}$, so the last expression becomes

$$\frac{(1-ae^{ib})(1-ae^{-ib})}{(a-e^{ib})(a-e^{-ib})}.$$

Multiplying terms we can see that the numerator and denominator cancel out, and we get $1$.

If $x=y$, as I said in the comment, the expression reduces to $-e^{2iyL}$, which also has squared modulus $1$.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you!